# MembershipUserCollection to IEnumerable<MembershipUser> for paging

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working in asp.net MVC 3 application. I want to show a list of users. I have created a function in repository like this:

```
 internal MembershipUserCollection GetUsers() {
           return Membership.GetAllUsers();
       }
```

I need IEnumerable object because I want to do paging as well. How can I do paging using MembershipUserCollection  or convert MembershipUserCollection  to IEnumerable

Please suggest

Comment: Just a guess, if `MembershipUserCollection` implements `IEnumerable`: `Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()` - although this probably won't support very efficient paging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Membership.GetAllUsers()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8swhya.aspx) does what it name suggests meaning that your paging won't be very efficient. If you want to implement an efficient paging, ideally at the database level, you should use the [following overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh1acb34.aspx) which allows you to pass the current page index and the desired page size:

```
internal IEnumerable<MembershipUser> GetUsers(
    int pageIndex, 
    int pageSize, 
    out int totalRecords
) 
{
    return Membership
        .GetAllUsers(pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords)
        .Cast<MembershipUser>();
}
```

The method returns the total number of records so that you can later correctly implement the paging at the UI level.